# How to share internet connection from ubuntu with RPi using Ethernet Cable

Tags: raspbian, ssh, linux, ubuntu, internet

I am a new user of Raspberry Pi. I have a Ubuntu PC (with Ubuntu 14.04 running). My RPi is booted with Raspbian OS.

I have added "ip=192.168.1.20" into my "cmdline.txt", at the end. Thus, in order to run my pi I use to SSH the IP "192.168.1.20".

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.20
```

Now, I need to install many more packages. I can't use "sudo apt-get install ", because I dont have any Internet connection. All I can do is to share my Ubuntu PC internet.

So, please guys help me with this.

Comment: Hello and welcome! I think you'll get more answers at http://unix.stackexchange.com as the question adresses not the RPi but the ubuntu laptop itself.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/171914/how-to-connect-share-your-internet-connection-wired-wireless

Answer (score 1):

You can set up Internet Connection sharing on Ubuntu. You would be better to ask this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions